# Not able to render a react component to a DOM node in different route templates in a node express app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Let me mention more info -

this is the project structure i am following in a node express app.

[image]

query - i have got following two routes with corresponding templates.

1) index route(default route) - index.hjs template and

2) movies route(created one) - movies.hjs template

Now i have react components in app.js , i want to render a react component to a DOM node (i.e. any div element) of movies.hjs template.

[by default react components in app.js are able to access DOM node of index.hjs but not able to access of a different template like movies.hjs].

Please help.

below code is in movies.hjs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> {{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Movie page </h1>
    <div id="movie_root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and react component in app.js is :

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Home from './components/layout/Home'

class MovieHomePage extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Home />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MovieHomePage />,document.getElementById('movie_root'))
```

Comment: Can you post the html of movies.hjs and the code from the file where you call ReactDOM.render() please?

Comment: Hi Stephen , i put code of movies.hjs and react component in edited post.please see